# What does "Trash everything you think you know" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Firstly sorry for my bad English.*

I'm translating an article about SMS Marketing. But I don't know what does `Trash everything you think you know` mean in the following context?

> First time customers who comb through these helpful resources observe
>   a better ROI from their SMS marketing campaigns. **Trash everything you
>   think you know about SMS marketing**. If you check out these resources
>   in the order that they appear, this immediate and affordable marketing
>   method will soon become second nature.

Comment: Trash = forget in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**to trash something**: to discard, to throw away something (to put something into the trash)

The sentence deconstructs thus:

```
Trash
     everything           you know about SMS marketing.
                you think
```

Or, plainly:

> Forget what you know (or rather: believe to know) about SMS marketing.

It's a request to follow only the suggested method in the subsequent text and to ignore all previous knowledge about the subject. (To my ear, advertising speak...)